# JavaScript: Получить позицию символа в строке

Tags: javascript

Реализую функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает позицию каждого символа в этой строке.

*Функция:*

```
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

*Должна вернуть:*

```
"20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11"
```

Не получается реализовать, мой алгоритм выдаёт ошибку -1. Какой алгоритм придумать чтобы реализовать, ума не приложу.

```js
function alphabetPosition(allLetters, letter) { 
  return allLetters.indexOf(letter); 
} 

var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]; 
var letter = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock"
var letterPosition = alphabetPosition(alphabet, letter);
```

Comment: потому что ты вместо буквы передаешь всю строку в параметре letter

Comment: @Grundy , точно, спасибо.

Comment: вообще, судя по всему возвращаться должна не _позиция каждого символа в этой строке_, а позиция каждой **буквы**

Comment: разобрался. спасибо. добавил "свое" решение для примера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве альтернативного решения, можно использовать регулярное выражение в методе replace.

Выделить в нем две группы - символы для замены на номера, и символы для замены на пустую строку.

В самой функции замены проверить к какому диапазону относится символ, большие или маленькие буквы, и в соответствии с этим вывести нужный номер

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  var length = text.length,
    ACode = 65,
    aCode = 97,
    map = {
      true: aCode - 1,
      false: ACode - 1
    };
  return text.replace(/([a-z])|([^a-z])/ig, function($0, char) {
    if (!char) return '';
    var charCode = char.charCodeAt(0);
    return (charCode - map[charCode >= aCode]) + ' ';
  }).trim();
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код все равно не выведет нужный результат, так как у вас алфавит только для строчных символов, а в строке есть и прописные (большие).

Чтобы не создавать массив с алфавитом, можно использовать функцию [`String.prototype.charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), которая возвращает код символа. Код символа "a" (строчная английская) равен `97`:

```
 'a'.charCodeAt(0); // 97
```

Т.е. можно подсчитать номер любой буквы в английском алфавите используя `symbol.charCodeAt(0) - 96` (a - 1, b - 2, c -3 и т.д.)

```
var sentence = 'The sunset sets at twelve o' clock';
var result = sentence
   .toLowerCase() // приводим все символы в строке к нижнему регистру
   .replace(/[^a-z-]/g, '') // удаляем все кроме букв a-z
   .split('') // преобразует строчку в массив
   .map(function(s) {
        return s.charCodeAt(0) - 96; // возвращаем номер буквы
   }
);

// на выходе получаем необходимый вам массив
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  let result = text.toLowerCase() // Переводим текст в нижний регистр
  .replace(/[^a-z-]/g, '') // Удаляем лишние знаки, останутся только буквы
  .split('') // Превращаем в массив
  .map(function(s) {
        // возвращаем номер буквы. Каждая буква имеет свой код, 
        // буква а имеет код 97 и мы от нее отняли 69 и теперь 
        // она имеет код 1, как в алфавите.
        return s.charCodeAt(0) - 96;
   })
  .join(' ') // Переводим массив в строку с разделителем в видел пробела
  return result; //возвращаем результат
  
};

console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

Answer (score 0):

возвращает позицию каждого символа в строке:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  return text.toLowerCase().split('')
        .filter( c => c >= 'a' & c <= 'z' )
        .map( c => c.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
        .join(' ');
}

console.log(alphabetPosition('n8_ovuu&'));
```